# Magento 2 : Retreiving Data From Database, Use it in Knockout UI Component in Checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs, data, getmodel

I have been developing a module for Magento2 Checkout that fills some information, not important what, this data resides in Magento's db, and I am able to access it via Magento database access layer.

My question is, how do I get this retrieve this data and use it in a Knockoutjs UI Component in Checkout?

Comment: Are you going to use it with existing component or new?

Comment: I am extending uiComponent into a new ui component

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to get this working by implementing a ConfigProvider via implementing `ConfigProviderInterface`.

```
<?php

namespace My\Plugin\Model;

class MyPluginConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        $config = [
            'store_address' => [
                'name' => $this->scopeConfig->getValue('general/store_information/name'),
                'city' => $this->scopeConfig->getValue('shipping/origin/city'),
                (...)
            ]
        ];
        return $config;
    }
}
```

Added it to `app/code/My/Plugin/etc/frontend/di.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="instore_config_provider" xsi:type="object">Premiergroup\InStoreShipping\Model\InStoreConfigProvider</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

And then, finally, called it from within my ko uiComponent:

```
define(
[
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'uiComponent'
],
function (
    $,
    ko,
    Component
) {
    'use strict';
    return Component.extend({
    (...)

    functionToBind: function () {
        var storeName = window.checkoutConfig.store_address.store_name;
        // do something with the storeName
```

I hope someone else finds this helpful and I can't find any documentation on this!

Answer (score 2):

In the phtml file where you get the Value from db write below code:

`.phtml` file code:

```
<script>
    window.myData = "<?php echo $datafromdb ?>";
</script>
```

in Knockout js you can access this data like:

```
define(
    [
        //your model
    ],
    function (url) {
        'use strict';

        return {
            mydata: window.myData,
        };
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi, since I am using UI components, it uses Knockout html templates, so there is no `phtml`.

Comment: Than you can refer this html file 
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address/details.html

method: currentBillingAddress()

Comment: That file doesn't really have anything to do with getting data from the database, just filling it in with a template. I found a way to do it via `ConfigProviderInterface`.